# Abrir PDF Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, impressão

Bom dia, Preciso Abrir PDF da minha tabela no clicar botão, está funcionando em todos os navegadores, menos no IE, a principio é só converter base64 em algo que o IE suporte, automático, via javascript, mais é isso que não estou conseguindo.

esse é meu JS

```
gerarRelatorio = function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt');
    var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document
            .getElementById("tabela"));

    var header = function(data) {
        doc.setTextColor(40);
        doc.setFontStyle('normal');
        doc.setFontSize(11);    
    };

    var options = {
        addPageContent : header,
        theme : 'striped',
        tableWidth : 'auto',
        margin : {
            top : 80
        },
        startY : false
    };

    doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);

    var data = doc.output('dataurl');
    var fileName = "pdf.pdf";
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var byteCharacters = atob('dataurl');
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var base64EncodedPDF = data;
        var dataURI = "data:application/pdf;base64," + data;
        window.open(dataURI, '_blank');
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + dados, '', 
        "height=600,width=800");
    }
    else {
        x = window.open();
        iframe = x.document.createElement('iframe')
        iframe.width = '100%'
        iframe.height = '100%'
        iframe.frameBorder = 0
        dados = doc.output('dataurl');
        iframe.style = "border: 0"
        iframe.src = 'data:application/pdf;base64' + dados
        x.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
}
```

Comment: eu peguei esse que diz que no IE Funciona mais nao achei solução no meu projeto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070627/internet-explorer-fails-opening-a-pdf-string-file-solved

Comment: Possível duplicata de [aparecer PDF no Internet Explorer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277912/aparecer-pdf-no-internet-explorer)